# Bypass 2GB Upload Limit IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, sharepoint-2010

IIS (7) is blocking my upload from client (asp.net code - .NET 3.5) to my server (sharepoint) because the file is larger than 2GB. From my research on the web, that appears to be the limit.

So how can we bypass this limit?

Client code :

```
string urlFile = "xxxxx"

Stream input = Telechargeur.FileContent
Stream output = new FileStream(urlFile,FileMode.OpenOrCreate)

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024*1024*5]
int nbRead = -1

while((nbRead = input.Read(buffer,0,buffer.Length))>0)
{
  output.Write(buffer,0,nbRead);
  output.Flush();

}

input.Close();
output.Close();
```

Server code :

```
string urlFile = "xxx"

Stream input = context.Request.InputStream; Stream output =  new FileStream(urlFile,FileMode.OpenOrCreate)

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024*1024*5]
    int nbRead = -1

    while((nbRead = input.Read(buffer,0,buffer.Length))>0)
    {
      output.Write(buffer,0,nbRead);
      output.Flush();

    }

    input.Close();
    output.Close();
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't say what version of SharePoint you are using I'll assume 2013. See the [Technet article on Software boundaries and limits for SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx) This is an architectural limit in the design of SharePoint, it cannot be bypassed. What you are trying to subvert here is actually THE scenario used in the article to define what a "boundary" is:

```
Boundaries are absolute limits that cannot be exceeded by design. It is
important to understand these limits to ensure that you do not make 
incorrect assumptions when you design your farm.

An example of a boundary is the 2 GB document size limit; you cannot 
configure SharePoint Server 2013 to store documents that are larger than 2 
GB. This is a built-in absolute value, and cannot be exceeded by design.
```

Even if you could convince SharePoint to let you bypass the limit, that is an extremely bad idea because it would leave your farm in an unsupported state. That means that when you call in for support with some weird problem and what you have done is discovered, you will be told that you will not get support on that farm until you rebuild it correctly.

It also occurred to me that [RBS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628583.aspx) might let you bypass this limit. Sorry, that wont do it either:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But in my case, I upload the file on server (in a directory) not in the content database. So, for me, the problem is IIS not SharePoint. Any Idea?

Comment: I am a little confused about the architecture of your solution. You say you are uploading to a SharePoint server, but not to SharePoint. I don't doubt that this is what you think you are doing, but I suspect that SharePoint is intercepting the request and rejecting your large upload.

Comment: You say you are uploading to a SharePoint server, but not to SharePoint. I suspect that SharePoint is intercepting the request and rejecting your large upload.

Are you saying that you have a virtual directory for SharePoint and a DIFFERENT one for this task? If that is the case, then it might work as the SharePoint internal WEBDAV implementation wont intercept your requests. If you are assuming that you can leverage the SharePoint WEBDAV functionality, you are mistaken. 

I would check the IIS logs and see who is handling your requests.

Comment: You're completely right, my bad. I just have one virtual directory. What I wanted to say, is that I don't upload in a content database, but put the file on the filesystem. I'm gonna try the neatupload API which seems to give me solution... I will do a return